# Multiple xmlagg in xmlagg

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, aggregate-functions

I have a problem, I need to create an xml that has a format like:

```
<Root>
<Bank>--Can be repeated
<ID> 
   <Credit>--Can be repeated
             <INFO> --Can be repeated
             </INFO>
   <Credit>
</ID>
</Bank>
</Root>
```

So this is like xmlagg, into xmlagg into xmlagg

I have a table that like this:

```
BANK|  ID  |  CREDIT |  INFO  ||
1      A1     B1        C1
1      A1     B1        C2
1      A1     B1        C3
1      A1     B2        D1
1      A1     B2        D2
1      A1     B1        C1
2      X1     Y1        Z1
```

I want to have XML like :

```
<Root>   
<Bank> 1 </Bank>
<ID> A1 </ID>
   <CREDIT> B1 
             <INFO> C1 </INFO>
             <INFO> C2 </INFO>
             <INFO> C2 </INFO>
   </CREDIT>
   <CREDIT> B2 
             <INFO> D1 </INFO>
             <INFO> D2 </INFO>
   </CREDIT>
</ID>
<BANK> 2 </BANK>
<ID> X1 </ID>
<CREDIT> Y1</CREDIT>
<INFO> Z1 </INFO>
</Root>
```

I hope you are getting my point, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very vague and the xml definition and example are inconsistent. Also assumed that the data in the xml should be distinct.

```
WITH src (bank, id, credit, info) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B1', 'C2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B1', 'C3' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B2', 'D1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B2', 'D2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1' FROM dual
),
credit_data AS (
    SELECT
        bank,
        id,
        XMLELEMENT("Credit", credit,
            XMLAGG(
                XMLELEMENT(INFO, info)
            )
        ) child_nodes
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM src)
    GROUP BY
        bank, id, credit
),
bank_data AS (
    SELECT
    XMLELEMENT("Bank", bank,
        XMLELEMENT("ID", id,
            XMLAGG(
                child_nodes
            )
        )
    ) bank_nodes
FROM
    credit_data
GROUP BY
    bank, id
)
SELECT
    XMLSERIALIZE(
        DOCUMENT
        XMLELEMENT("Root", NULL,
            XMLAGG(
                bank_nodes
            )
        )
        INDENT SIZE = 2
    ) xml
FROM
    bank_data;
```